# How does the ProgressBar.PerformStep() function work?

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I'm quite confused about progress bar in VB.net, here is my code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ProgressBar_my.Minimum = 0
    ProgressBar_my.Maximum = 10
    ProgressBar_my.Step = 1
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ProgressBar_my.PerformStep()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    If 1 = 1 Then
        ProgressBar_my.PerformStep()
        ProgressBar_my.PerformStep()
    End If

    'Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)

End Sub
```

For the above code, what I expected is that after I click `Button1`, the progress bar will increase the progress status by 1, then it will pause for `5 sec`, then it will increase the progress status by 2 at once.

However, after I ran the above code, what I saw was that after I click `Button1`, the progress bar will increase by 3 continually after `5 sec`.

Can someone tell me why it behaves like this and How should I program my code so that I can increase by 1, then pause 5 sec and then increase by 2?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the following code as the first line inside Button1_Click: `Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder()` Then add this line before all ProgressBar_my.PerformStep: `builder.AppendLine(String.Format("Value={0}, Minimum={1}, Maximum={2}, Step={3}", ProgressBar_my.Value, ProgressBar_my.Minimum, ProgressBar_my.Maximum, ProgressBar_my.Step))`. Finally add this as your last code inside Button1_Click: `MsgBox(builder.ToString())`.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå How is this supposed to help?

Comment: This will show if there's a difference between the displayed progress value (GUI) and the values hold by the progressbar.

Comment: You do realise that you have two different progress bar objects in you code don't you? `ProgressBar1` in Form_Load and `ProgressBar_my` in the button click event

Comment: Yes, I knew, its a typo error. I corrected it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are seeing (or not seeing) is the fact that the progress bar takes a finite amount of time to advance each step.

When you call `Threading.Thread.Sleep` on the UI thread this stops the progress bar from being redrawn until after the `Sleep`

What you should do is update the progress bar on a background worker instead, then I think you will see the effect you desire.

Add a BackgroundWorker to your form

Change your button click code to start the worker:

```
Private Sub frmSO_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ProgressBar_my.Minimum = 0
    ProgressBar_my.Maximum = 10
    ProgressBar_my.Step = 1
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync
End Sub
```

Then perform the update in the DoWork event:

```
'define a delegate to handle updates to the UI thread
Private Delegate Sub PerformStepCallback()

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim cb As PerformStepCallback = AddressOf ProgressBar_my.PerformStep
    Me.BeginInvoke(cb)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Me.BeginInvoke(cb)
    Me.BeginInvoke(cb)
End Sub
```

Comment: How am i supposed to do that, update the progress bar on a background worker instead?

Comment: I ran your code but it turned out that the the progress bar didn't change at all..

Comment: Are you still setting the min max and step properties?

Comment: Yes, you mean I shouldn't?

Comment: Won't that throw a cross thread exception?  You're updating a UI control from a different thread than the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call `Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)`, which will, well, pause the current thread. But that also means that the window won't be redrawn, so you see the effect of the first call to `PerformStep` only after the thread is no longer paused.

You can use another thread for wait and the second update; the easiest way in this case is using the Task Parallel Library:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
    Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(Sub()
                                      ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
                                      ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
                                  End Sub, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  Matt Wilko for giving me the clue. Here is my code.

From the Components tab of the Toolbox, add a `BackgroundWorker` component named `backgroundWorker2`. Create `DoWork` and `ProgressChanged` event handlers for the `BackgroundWorker`.

The following code will initiate the Component.

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    BackgroundWorker2.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    BackgroundWorker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
End Sub
```

Call `RunWorkerAsync` when the button is clicked and the background worker is not running.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If BackgroundWorker2.IsBusy <> True And ProgressBar_my.Value < 6 Then
        BackgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_DoWork_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                                       ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) _
                                       Handles BackgroundWorker2.DoWork
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)

    worker.ReportProgress(1)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    worker.ReportProgress(1)
    worker.ReportProgress(1)
End Sub
```

The following event is raised when every time the `ReportProgress` method is called.

```
Private Sub backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                                              ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) _
                                              Handles BackgroundWorker2.ProgressChanged
    ProgressBar_my.PerformStep()
End Sub
```

More information about the `BackgroundWorker`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx